# Reverse wstring in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, locale

I need to reverse wstring. I have such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::wstring s;
    std::getline(std::wcin, s);
    for (const auto &i : s) {
        std::wcout << (int) i << " ";
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << s << std::endl;

    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ANSI characters are encoded in 1 byte, and I can easily reverse them:

```
echo -n "papa" | ./reverse
112 97 112 97
papa
apap
```

But when I enter cyrillic text, that are encoded more than 1 bytes, I get such output:

```
echo -n "папа" | ./reverse
208 191 208 176 208 191 208 176
папа
�пап�
```

How can I properly reverse that string?

P.S. I'm using OS X.

Comment: If the encoding is utf-8, then why do you use wide character types?

Comment: @user2079303 With `std::string` I get such output: `-48 -65 -48 -80 -48 -65 -48 -80
папа
�пап�`

Comment: Yes, I didn't imply that was your problem, just a confusion.

Comment: Did you see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199260/how-do-i-reverse-a-utf-8-string-in-place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system, OS X, uses UTF-8.  So there is no reason for you to use `wstring` or `wchar_t`.  And indeed this is where the confusion comes from!

You see, when you call `getline()` with a `wstring` on OS X, it does not read wide characters at all.  The characters are indeed four bytes each, but they hold the same 0-255 range of values that they would if you used a regular "narrow" string.  So when you pipe your Cyrillic characters to your program, you end up with a `wstring` of length 8, because C++ doesn't understand UTF-8, but your terminal does (hence it looks like four characters in the terminal but 8 in C++).

A commenter on your question was right to point out this question: [How do I reverse a UTF-8 string in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199260/how-do-i-reverse-a-utf-8-string-in-place) - that is really all you need, once you realize that you aren't dealing with wide strings at all.