# What does "in-place" mean?

Tags: semantics

> Reverse words in a string (words are
>   separated by one or more spaces). Now
>   do it in-place.

What does in-place mean?

Comment: Check out this thread for tips on how to do it in C/C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c

Comment: @Banang: although this is answering a different question (reversing a string, rather than the words in a string, e.g. "dog bites man" becomes "man bites dog" rather than "nam setib god")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585507/sorting-in-place may explain it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In-place means that you should update the original string rather than creating a new one.

Depending on the language/framework that you're using this could be impossible. (For example, strings are immutable in .NET and Java, so it would be impossible to perform an in-place update of a string without resorting to some evil hacks.)

Comment: For .NET or Java the question could be rephrased to talk about an array of chars or a StringBuilder

Answer (score 10):

In-place algorithms can only use `O(1)` extra space, essentially. Array reversal (essentially what the interview question boils down to) is a classic example. The following is taken from Wikipedia:

> Suppose we want to reverse an array of n items. One simple way to do this is:
>
> ```
> function reverse(a[0..n])
>     allocate b[0..n]
>     for i from 0 to n
>        b[n - i] = a[i]
>     return b
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, this requires `O(n)` extra space to create the array `b`, and allocation is often a slow operation. If we no longer need `a`, we can instead overwrite it with its own reversal using this in-place algorithm:
>
> ```
> function reverse-in-place(a[0..n])
>     for i from 0 to floor(n/2)
>        swap(a[i], a[n-i])
> ```

Sometimes doing something in-place is VERY HARD. A classic example is general non-square matrix transposition.

#### See also

- [In-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)
- [In-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)

Comment: is non-square matrix transposition even possible to do in-place? Surely it requires different dimensions on each side.
a 2x3 array becoming a 3x2 array?

Comment: @penguat: the matrix would be stored in a 1D array of 6 elements. Transposition switches from row-major to column-major and vice versa, e.g. `ABCDEF` to `ADBECF`.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I see now how an in-place transposition could be tricky, and require an awful lot of thinking before implementation.

Answer (score 7):

You should change the content of the original string to the reverse without using a temporary storage variable to hold the string.

Comment: Isn't this impossible? You'd at least need a loop counter or pointer, probably 2.

Comment: Well, I meant a storage variable to hold temporary values. Depending on the language you'll indeed need a counter or a pointer.

Comment: Charles refers to temporary storage that hold the ‘string’,not counters or pointers.@SimonNickerson