# what does 'in place' exactly mean in simple terms when people say "random.shufle shuffles the sequence 'in place' "?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle, in-place

I'm having trouble understanding what people mean when they say "random.shufle shuffles the sequence 'in-place'" when referring to why directly printing out random.shuffle returns the value 'None' instead of just the shuffled list itself.

Referring to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects) in specific.

What does 'in place' exactly mean here? Please explain in newbie terms if possible, beginner here. Thank you.

talking about this bit of code

```
import random

b = [object(), object()]

print(random.shuffle(b))
```

which prints out:
`None`

Another question like this exists on here but it doesn't explain is simple/beginner terms, more complex ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "in-place" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779797/what-does-in-place-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a list to the shuffle function. The list will be shuffled (pseudo-randomly rearranged). The function does not return anything (apart from implicit None). Thus your list will be modified.

This could be demonstrated as follows:

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

shuffle(my_list)

print(my_list)
```

An output could be:

```
[1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

Therefore you can see that the list itself has been modified - i.e., "in place"