# returning a string from a c++ function

Tags: c++, string, function, words

I'm a beginner and I've been going through a book on C++, and I'm on a chapter on functions. I wrote one to reverse a string, return a copy of it to main and output it.

string reverseInput(string input);

```
int main()
{
    string input="Test string";
    //cin>>input;
    cout<<reverseInput(input);
    return 0;
}

string reverseInput(string input)
{
    string reverse=input;
    int count=input.length();
    for(int i=input.length(), j=0; i>=0; i--, j++){
        reverse[j]=input[i-1];
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

The above seems to work. The problem occurs when I change the following code:

```
string input="Test string";
```

to:

```
string input;
cin>>input;
```

After this change, the reverse function returns only the reverse of the first inputted word, instead of the entire string. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Lastly, is there a more elegant way of doing this by using references, without making a copy of the input, so that the input variable itself is modified?

Comment: Your reverse function has a bug in it.  You should use `i>0` for the `for` condition.  On the last iteration `i==0` and `j==input.length()` resulting in `reverse[input.length()]=input[-1]`, both of which are out of bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with `cin`. It stops reading after the first space character is read.

See the "cin and strings" section of this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

You can use `getline(cin, input);` to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

`cin >> input` reads a word. To read an entire line you should use getline

```
getline(cin, input);
```

A debugger is very useful in this cases, you can just see the values of the variables stepping through the program.

A simple cout << input; would have helped you too but if you still don't have a good IDE with integrate debugger I would suggest you to use one. Eclipse is good and open source. Visual studio 2010 express is good and free if you are on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will start using a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

`cin>>input;`  reads a word, not a line.

Use e.g. `getline(cin, input);` to read a line

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [`istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)

It takes an entire line from a stream you give, e.g. `cin` and saves it into a `string` variable. Example:

```
getline(cin, input);
```

[`cin.getline(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) would work on C-style character buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Inplace reverse function was already answered in detail here:

[How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: This won't help in his case, as he still reads the string incorrectly.

Comment: Agree, but getting only first word was already answered several times :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, I overread that he explicitly asked for an in-place version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `std::cin` reads character till it encounters a character for which [`std::isspace(c)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isspace/) returns `true`.  So spaces and newlines are all such characters which returns `true` when passing to `std::isspace`.

So what you need basically is, [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/):

```
std::string input;
if ( std::getline(std::cin, input))
{
    std::cout << reverseInput(input);
}
else
{
    std::cout <<"error while reading from standard input stream";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for your question about references and copying:

```
string& reverseInput(string& input)
{
    for (i = 0, j = input.length()-1; i < j; i++, j--) 
    {
         char c = input[i];
         input[i] = input[j];
         input[j] = c;
    }
    return input;
}
```

You pass your argument as reference, and you return a reference. No copying involved, and in a body, you don't define any new string, you are working on the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error in your reverse function, but the standard behaviour of `istream::operator>>`, which only reads until the first whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cin.getline(), cin >> s will only read the first word (delimited by space)