# Issues with reversing a string in place

Tags: c, string

I am writing a code to reverse a string in place:

```
void ReverseInPlace(char * x)
{
    char * end = x;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    char temp;
    while(*end)
    {
        ++end;//point tol end 
        ++i;//count the lenght
    }
    --end;
    printf("%s",end);

    printf("%d",i);
    while(i)
    {
        temp = *end;
        printf("%s","\n");
        printf("%c",temp);

        end--;
        x++;
        i--;
    }
    printf("%s","\n");//blank line
    printf("%s","\n");//blank line
    printf("%s","-----");//blank line
    printf("%s",x);//print original 
}
```

Here are my confusions:
Even though I am able to print the characters in reverse, I want to reverse the string without using an array

I get error when I try to do the following:

```
*x = temp;
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? If it's like `ReverseInPlace("hi")` then it won't work because you are modifying a string in non-writable memory

Comment: in your code `x` is a `char *` and `temp` is a `char`, so the expression statement `*x = temp;` is fine and you should not get an error. What error you get?

Comment: @danihp he's saying it crashes when he adds `*x = temp;`

Comment: yes I am calling the function like ReverseInPlace("123456789");

Comment: Yes I get crash when I do *x = temp

Comment: You can't modify a string literal. That's what Seth was trying to tell you. The compiler allows you to treat literals as if they were not declared `const`, but you should never do this because attempting to modify them produces undefined behavior. The way you're calling the function is incorrect and bound to fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <string.h> // strlen

void swap(char* a , char* b)
{
    char tmp;
    tmp=*a;
    (*a) = (*b);
    (*b) = tmp;
}

void ReverseInPlace(char * x)
{
    char * end = x;
    int i,j,length;
    char temp;

    length = strlen(x);

    //swap 1st with last, then 2nd with last-1, etc.  Till we reach the middle of the string.
    for(i=0,j=length-1 ; i<j ; ++i,--j)
        swap( &x[i] , &x[j]);
}

main (){
    char str[] = "123456789";
    ReverseInPlace(str);
    //ReverseInPlace("1234"); // this would lead to error, because "1234", can not be modified
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

After middle is reached, you would swap elements which were already swapped by previous iterations.  For illustration:

```
char* x = "1234";
1 2 3 4
4 2 3 1
4 3 2 1 // already reversed!
4 2 3 1
1 2 3 4 // if we continue till i==length-1 && j=0 , then we just get where we started
```

Comment: I have a question :*a = *b : how come it does not crash ?

Comment: a - pointer to char - address of some place in memory. Imagine it to be something like 756483. 
*a - refers to actual value stored at that address. 
Same thing with b and *b.
So in the end *a=*b, just takes value from memory segment that has address b and puts that value into memory segment that has address a.
Or I have misunderstood your question?

Comment: @RahulRai It actually will crash if you pass ReverseInPlace a literal string.  Note the commented out line in the main function. If *a isn't writable memory then as soon as the program tries to store the contents of *b in *a it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are doing this:

```
ReverseInPlace("123456789");
```

You need to do something like this:

```
char str[] = "123456789";
ReverseInPlace(str);
```

Doing it the latter way allocates storage which you can modify, as opposed to modifying a literal string, which is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

`char *p="abcd123";` // ........string literal stored in read only memory mostly in `text segment`(where the code is stored) so you should never change value here as it may crash your program by writing onto code. Here p is pointing to address which maybe in text segment.

`char q[]="abcd1234";` //..... the values can be changed and array size can be modified but address cant be changed because the array is nothing but a constant pointer. That's the problem with your code .....you are calling the function and parameter is a string literal whereas it should be a constant pointer. Further the storage class here is `stack` so u can modify the values.