# Error at "cout << " in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to reverse a char array in C++. Here is my code :

```
void reverse(char s[]);
int main()
{
    char s [] = "Harry";
    cout << reverse(s) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    if( strlen( s ) > 0 ) {
        char* first = &s[ 0 ];
        char* last = &s[ strlen( s ) - 1 ];
        while( first < last ) {
            char tmp = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = tmp;
            ++first;
            --last;
        }
        return;
    }
```

However, I got an error at cout << reverse(s) << endl; that line which located in main method and I have no idea why.The error message is no operator match these operands. Anybody can help me fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/198264/195488

Comment: Can you post the `#include` that you have in your file?

Comment: `void reverse(char s[])`.

Comment: or better yet: `#include <algorithm>` `std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());`

Comment: I only put #include <iostream>. Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: @0A0D, you mean, `std::reverse(s, s+strlen(s));`

Comment: @LBg: No, I am encouraging him to use `std::string`... no reason to use `char` arrays in C++

Comment: 0A0D, Thanks for the link and I've solved it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `reverse` function has a return type of `void`. This means it doesn't return anything so your `cout << reverse()` has nothing to output.

Seems like instead you meant to do:

```
char s [] = "Harry";
reverse(s);
cout << s << endl;
```

Alternatively, you can make `reverse` return a `char*` and put `return s;` at the end of its body. However, that would be a little strange, since you're using both the argument and the return value for the same function output. Just use it as above.

Of course, you could do this much more easily if you make use of the standard library; use `std::string` and `std::reverse`:

```
std::string s = "Test";
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/a8aeMm).

Comment: Oh okay okay thanks alot. I just learnt pointer today and our teacher asks us to write this using pointer. Thanks tho