# Example of ICU bidi usage with C api

Tags: c, internationalization, arabic, icu, bidi

Need help with simple example using C and ICU bidi API. I am newbie in C and official  [documentation](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubidi_8h.html) from ICU is hard for me to understand. I do understand that we need some kind of structure (`UBiDi *pBiDi`) with needed paragraph of text created before any bidi algorithm method execution (probably `ubidi_setPara()`).

So the question is .. could someone show me how to execute a simple example with passing string `"foo ARABIC bar"` to method and getting the result like `"foo CIBARA bar"` or something similar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are working with unicode strings?

Comment: Yes. I want simple example with code that returns properly reversed unicode or string back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c

Comment: It should be done with ICU C api for RTL unicode text (like arabic). Here is the link to library [API](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubidi_8h.html)