# Why does this code for reversing a string not work in C++?

Tags: c++

```
string binary = "12345";
string binary2 = "";
size = binary.size() - 1;
for (i = size; i >= 0; i--)
{
    binary2[size - i] = binary[i];
}
cout << binary2;
```

I keep getting a subscript error during run time. But, I don't know what the problem is. I would appreciate an explanation if possible.

Comment: Because `binary2` is an empty string? Anyway, `string binary2(binary.rbegin(), binary.rend());`.

Comment: @juanchopanza So, I just put a space?

Comment: @user29568, No, you can't subscript it past its size.

Comment: No, you use the line I suggested in my first comment :-)

Comment: binary2.resize(binary.size()); http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/. With that said, please use @juanchopanza s method.

Comment: @dutt That would fail too.

Comment: Can I understand why the down-votes?

Comment: Aha, didn't know that. Alright then. Don't use my method :}

Comment: @dutt: Reserve is not resize.

Comment: if `i` is unsigned as `std::size_t`, you got a infinite loop with UB inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`binary2` is empty. It has no characters in it. Accessing characters with `[]` does not magically create character that do not already exist: it only changes the value of existing characters. You are trying to change the value of characters that do not exist.

You can either initialise `binary2` to `"     "`, like this:

```
string binary = "12345";
string binary2(binary.size(), ' ');
// now your loop
```

or you can do string reversing properly:

```
string binary = "12345";
string binary2(binary.rbegin(), binary.rend());
```

Comment: A more rigid option for #1 in case `binary` changes would be `string binary2(binary1.size(), '\0');` (or another character of your choosing).

Comment: I haven't learned that yet. Thanks for the addition. Out of curiosity, is their a way to initialize a string to a certain size that is given in a number and can change. Because if I used spaces and binary changed to 123456. It wouldn't work,

Comment: @user29568: Why are you not using any documentation? There is a string constructor to do this. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To be honest, our teacher just throws things on the board and doesn't really explain things. So, I haven't learned that either. I use Programming and Principles using C++ by Stoustrup to study. But, I haven't reached that far in yet.

Comment: Thank You for offering a full explanation and answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your binary2 string is empty. This could be fixed by appending to it instead.
However a little bit of searching led me to the following answer by Greg Rogers found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/198210/2299061

```
#include <algorithm>
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: That is for reversing a string in place, but OP wants a second string to be a reversed version of a first one. In this case, the reverse operator initialization seems more efficient. But +1, `std::reverse` is often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

string `binary2 = ""` should be changed to string `binary2 = "     ";`

Comment: Yes, we've covered that.