# Modify the content of char* str

Tags: c

I'm trying to reverse the string via void function, but segmentation fault occurs for "str" it's stored read-only memory (as I known from searching existing thread in the forum).

I tried to use strcpy(copy, str) in "reverse" function but it's just reversing the newly created char array "copy" which cannot be returned to main function. I don't want to use printf("%s", copy) in the reverse function to print the reversed string.

Is there anyway to reverse `str`

1. Without changing it to `char str[] = "Hello"`
2. Without changing the code in `main()` function
3. Keep the function type of `reverse()` as `void`?

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
  int l = strlen(str);
  char temp;
  int j = length - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
  {
     temp = str[i];
     str[i] = str[j];
     str[j] = temp;
     --j;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char* str = "Hello";
   reverse(str);
   printf("%s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Short answer to (at least questions 1 & 3) is "no."  A "char *" allocated like that is going to be read-only.  You can't change the pointer with your current `reverse (char *str)` function signature.  You either need a writable source array, or a way to allocate new memory in reverse (and return that new pointer.)

Comment: "Hello" is a string constant and has static scope, so the compiler may place it in read-only memory.  If you want to reverse it you should make a copy of the data in main (using strcpy) and pass a pointer to the copied data into reverse().

Comment: You've listed three possible solutions. Is there any reason you don't want to use any of them?

Comment: With the restrictions you've placed, you can't. You can't modify a string literal in C.

Comment: well, I'm trying to figure out is there any other way that I missed out apart from these 3 possible solutions.

Comment: @Matt I added another alternative to do this, please read my answer again. Two of the three requierements are really impossible.

Comment: @iharob Perfect bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you cannot modify string literals.

Try like this:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
reverse(str);
```

above, `str` is no longer a string literal, it's an array initialized to `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`, so you can modify it's contents if you want.

Or you can use `malloc()`

```
char *str = malloc(6);
if (str != NULL)
 {
    strcpy(str, "Hello");
    reverse(str);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str);
    /* And never forget to `free' */ 
    free(str);
 }
```

When defining string literals use `const` to protect it from being modified, at least from accidentally doing so.

There is no way to satisfy these requirements

> 1. Without changing it to `char str[] = "Hello"`
>
>    *Because you cannot modify string literals*
> 2. Without changing the code in `main()` function
>
>    *Because that would require the program to modify a string literal and **YOU CAN'T***

The third requirement, does not impose any problem at all.

Answer (score -4):

everytime you use a pointer that you have to use a `malloc()` in C or `new()` in C++ which could probably be the issue. but you can always cast de-reference anything to its address back to a pointer like i did below

DEMO: http://ideone.com/LnOtDL

```
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* str)
{
  int length = strlen(str);
  char temp;
  int j = length - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
  {
     temp = str[i];
     str[i] = str[j];
     str[j] = temp;
     --j;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char str[] = "Hello";
   reverse(&str[0]);
   printf("%s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know but hell it works.. even if it complicates the code.. I'm not a programmer i'm a reverse engineerer but I think i found the issue it's the pointer to string without a `malloc/new`. I'll try to fix up the answer to make it better

Comment: It doesn't work at all, it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: ya it works now sorry I did that way to quick without even checking it even had typo's

Comment: It really doesn't work trust me, it might appear to work but it doesn't. Change the program a little bit leaving this part as it is, and it might do something very unexpected.

Comment: Ok i will fix it.. i think it's better now, it's pointing to the first element in the array

Comment: `&str[0]` is redundant. `str` decays to a pointer when passed to a function which already points to the first element in the array.

Comment: screw it i'll just quietly leave you guys are all above me I can't stay here too long.

Comment: @PCLuddite it adds to clarity of the code though, so not redundant.  You could also argue that the spaces either side of the `=` signs are redundant.

Comment: It's actually hard for me to distinguish the three tokens with the lack of spaces.

Comment: @M.M I would disagree. It makes sense to pass a pointer to a string to a function that requires a pointer to the string. `&str[0]` just clutters code. It's not the same as arguing that spaces are redundant because spaces make code easier to read. Surrounding a pointer with superfluous operators does not.