# alternative for strcpy in C++

Tags: c++

Hey all I am new to c++ and I am working on a simple project which takes an inputted string and outputs the string in reverse. I coded the program using what I remembered from programming classes I took years ago however I keep getting a warning for using strcpy and it will not compile on the command prompt and I am not exactly sure the alternative way. Please help. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string reverse;
    char *head, *tail, *cstr, temp;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a string: " << endl;
    cin >> reverse;

    cstr = new char[reverse.size() + 1];

    strcpy(cstr, reverse.c_str());
    head = &cstr[0];
    tail = &cstr[reverse.size() - 1];

    cout << "The string inverted is: " << endl;

    while (head <= tail) {
        temp = cstr[i];
        cstr[i] = *tail;
        *tail = temp;
        *tail--;
        *head++;
        i++;

    }
    cout << cstr;
    cout << "\n";

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: *"programming classes I took years ago"* Like, in the early 90s? Seriously, read some up to date learning material if you are going to write C++.

Comment: [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) perhaps?

Comment: You never declared `strcpy`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to use `std::string`, and do your best to forget that you ever even heard of `strcpy`. I'd probably write something on this general order:

```
std::string forward;
std::cin >> forward;

std::string reverse{forward.rbegin(), forward.rend()};

std::cout << "The string reversed is: " << reverse;
```

If you prefer to reverse the string in place, the standard library has an `std::reverse` for that:

```
std::string reverse;
std::cin >> reverse;

std::reverse(reverse.begin(), reverse.end());

std::cout << "The string reversed is: " << reverse;
```

Answer (score 0):

I define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in all my projects to shut these warnings up.

since standard `strcpy` can cause buffer overflow and memore corruption you can use `strcpy_s` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You could use memcpy to copy your string. strcpy probably uses memcpy internally though.

Comment: He asked for a C++ alternative. I don't think you are answering that.