# string has no member named 'reverse'

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a string (c++, compiling with g++).
Isn't string considered a container for the algorithm functions?

This is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string str = "hello";
    str.reverse(str.begin(), str.rbegin());

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did you mean std::reverse?

Comment: You should consult the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) when you use something new and it doesn't work to make sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: yes, `string` is a container, but no `string` has no `reverse` you probably meant `std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end())`. And your mixing of reverese and forward iterators is weird. I avoid reverse iterators whenever I can, because I always get it wrong, but this looks wrong too

Comment: I think you want to use `std::reverse`, the [STD function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) in the `algorithm` header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Your error demonstrates why algorithms exist.  Note that `std::reverse` works with any sequence container.  That's why there is no `std::string::reverse`, `std::array::reverse`, `std::vector::reverse`, etc.  The same `std::reverse` works for all of them.

Comment: You’re right that `std::string` does not have a member function named `reverse`. No containers do. RTFM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class template does not have a member function called `reverse`. There is a [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function located in the `<algorithm>` header. You probably want to use it in a following manner:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
int main() {
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Note the use of `str.end()` in place of your `str.rbegin()`. You can also define a new string and use the string constructor overload that accepts reverse iterators:

```
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::string reversestr(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has no method `reverse`. But [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) exists:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << "\n"; // prints "olleh"
}
```