# How to save a reversed string as a new string?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a palindrome checker. So in order to tackle this problem I figured I would compare the original string to the reversed one. However how can I save the reversed string without overwriting the old one?

`reverse(myString.begin(), myString.end())` will reverse my string but it replaces myString and doing `string reversedString = reverse(myString.begin(), myString.end());` does not work. Here is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    string myString;
    getline(cin, myString);
    cout << endl;

    string reversedString = reverse(myString.begin(), myString.end());

    cout << reversedString;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: @Kaldrr: This question here is the opposite of your finding. OP wants *not* in place reverse :-)

Comment: It is useful to observe a string and its reverse always exist in the same location. It's good to answer questions on point but sometimes the better solution is preferable.

Comment: *reverse iterator* provided by `rbegin`, `rend` might help.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't create an new string **just to check palindrome** (unless you have some other use case). To check palindrome you can simply create two pointers/iterators from start and end and check for exact match untill both pointers reach the middle/crossover. This would save you time and space which is a treasure to a coder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the new string, by using the reverse iterators:

```
string reversedString(myString.rbegin(), myString.rend());
```

Further by using standard algorithms and the reverse iterators You can do (since C++14)

```
const bool is_palindrome = std::equal(myString.begin(), myString.end(),
                                      myString.rbegin(), myString.rend()));
```

Comment: Or even `auto midSize = s.size() / 2; bool res = std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + midSize,
                                      s.rbegin(), s.rbegin() + midSize));`.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I save the reversed string without overwriting the old one?

`std::string` has both a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator making both these possible:

```
std::string reversedString(myString); // copy constructor
// or
std::string reversedString;
reversedString = myString;            // copy assignment

// finally
std::reverse(reversedString.begin(), reversedString.end());
```

And as others have pointed out, a `std::string` can be constructed using iterators. By constructing the new string using `myString`s reverse iterators `rbegin()` and `rend()` you can create your reversed string directly without the need to call `std::reverse`:

```
std::string reversedString(myString.rbegin(), myString.rend());
```

For the task at hand, to find out if it's a palindrome, you don't need any of the above. Just compare the characters in `myString` in-place from **`begin()`** and **`rbegin()`** towards the middle of the string:

```
bool is_palindrome = 
    std::equal(myString.begin(), 
               std::next(myString.begin(), str.size() / 2U),
               myString.rbegin()
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the string before reversing it:

```
string reversedString = myString;
reverse(reversedString.begin(), reversedString.end()); // reverse is now done on the copy
```