# Reverse string with pointers and functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I am trying to create a program that reverses a string with pointers and functions in C++, but so far, my method is only returning an empty string rather than a reversed one.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void invertS(string *str_ptr );

int main()
{
   string value {"Hello"};
   string *str_ptr {nullptr};
   str_ptr = &value;
   invertS(str_ptr);
   cout << value;
};

void invertS(string *str_ptr) {
    string str = *str_ptr;
    string temp = "";
    int length = str.length();
    int j = length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp[i] = str[j];
        j--;
    };
    *str_ptr = temp;
};
```

The result is always just an empty string.
Note that I'm assigning the string referenced by str_ptr to a new string inside the function so that I can use .length on the string. Since .length cannot be used on a pointer as far as I know. If there's a better way to do that, I'd also appreciate to know how it goes.

Comment: Think about the *size* of the string `temp`... Do you ever make it bigger?

Comment: _Since .length cannot be used on a pointer as far as I know._ You could do `str_ptr->length()` instead.

Comment: Just use [`std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) where s is the `std::string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: `std::string newstring{oldstring.rbegin(), oldstring.rend()};` if you want a reversed copy instead of reversing it in-place.

Comment: No offense but that question you're linking to has a ridiculously verbose solution whereas the one provided here by Yasir Khan is much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing the temp string with zero length and then trying to access the indexes (which should fail IMO). The easy fix is to create a copy of the original string so that length is the same as the original string to be reversed.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void invertS(string *str_ptr );

int main()
{
   string value {"Hello"};
   string *str_ptr {nullptr};
   str_ptr = &value;
   invertS(str_ptr);
   cout << "Reversed string: " << value << endl;
};

void invertS(string *str_ptr) {
    string str = *str_ptr;
    string temp {str};
    int length = str.length();

    int j = length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp[i] = str[j];
        j--;
    };
    *str_ptr = temp;
};
```

Comment: "*which should fail IMO*" Noone can say what "should" happen when UB is involved. It may do absolutely anything.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just checked and it has "undefined behavior"

Answer (score 1):

You make a new string of length `0` here:

```
string temp = "";
```

And then later you do this:

```
temp[i] = str[j];
```

However, the size of this string is still `0`, so this is incorrect. You have to resize your string after making it:

```
temp.resize(str.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's just for sake of education/learning, but you should avoid using pointers when we have so much rich C++ library.

To fix the above code, you need to append characters to the `temp`. Size `temp` has size zero. Or resize it with `length`

`temp += str[j];`