# How do I get proper output when I reverse a string in C using pointers

Tags: c, c-strings

I am trying to reverse a string in C with pointers but the output is really weird. The logic seems good but I am not sure why it gets outputted like this. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20], reverse_str[20], *pointer;
    int i = 0;

    printf("%s", "Enter any string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    pointer = str;

    int string_length = strlen(pointer);

    //int count = 0;
    for (int i = string_length; i > 0; i--){
        reverse_str[i -1] = *pointer;
        pointer++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", string_length);
    printf("Original string = %s\n", str);
    printf("Reversed string = %s\n", reverse_str);

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Enter any string: Hello

Original string = Hello
Reversed string = olleH╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Hello
```

Comment: You forgot to append a null terminator to `reverse_str`.

Comment: you forgot to NUL-terminate `reverse_str`. E.g. add `reverse_str[string_length] = '\0';` after the loop

Comment: or before it, it doesn't matter when.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c++

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean with "before it, it doesn´t matter when"? The string needs to be terminated by a `\0`, not preceded by it.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio You can assign the null terminator as Ingo suggested before the loop, it doesn't have to be after the loop.

Comment: @Barmor Ah, before the loop; I´d thought you mean at the beginning of the respective string. lol

Comment: regarding: `int string_length = strlen(pointer);`   The function: `strlen()` returns type `size_t` not `int`, so `string_length` should be declared as `size_t`, not `int` and everything that uses that variable should also be of type: `size_t`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", str);`   When using the 'input format conversion' specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because these specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is when the role of null terminator comes in which is often ignored as a silly bit of information by beginners.

In C, every string is terminated by a null character because there needs to be some way to know when a particular string ends starting from its initial location in memory. If you properly initialize the string or put in `\0` appropriately then the string can be displayed as is. Otherwise every character in memory starting from the zeroth index of the string will be displayed until it encounters a null character. This is how a `printf("%s", str)` works, in simple words.

You get that weird output because of this reason. [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344603/are-c-strings-always-null-terminated-or-does-it-depend-on-the-platform) explains it much better.

**Solution:**

Add `reverse_str[string_length] = '\0';` after you reverse your string using that for loop, so that your resultant string is properly null terminated.

**Bonus:**

And the reason why you got a considerably sane output is that you were lucky since the compiler allocated `str` and `reverse_str` close to each other in a direction such that even if you miss the null terminator on `reverse_str` you hit the null terminator of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

To print a string, the string needs a NUL-terminator `\0` but `reverse_str` doesn´t have one.

You need to set a `\0` at the end of `revers_str`, like:

```
reverse_str[string_length] = '\0';
```

to make it print the right output.