# Segmentation fault and 'free' called on a pointer to an unallocated object

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program to simply reverse a string in C. However, when I try to copy the contents of the temp string I made into the original string, I get a segmentation fault. Also, when I try to free the memory I allocated for my test string I get a warning which says " 'free' called on a pointer to an unallocated object "
Here is my code:

```
void reverseString(char* str, size_t size) {
    char *temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);
    int j = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i] = str[j];
        j--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        str[i] = temp[i];
    }

    free(temp);
    return;
}


int main() {
    char* result = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 10));
    result = "Forty-two";

    reverseString(result, strlen(result));

    printf("%s", result);

    free(result);
    result = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `result = "Forty-two"` doesn't copy the string to the allocated memory, it re-assigns the pointer.

Comment: 1 - sizeof(str) returns size of pointer not length of the literal.
2 - Array index starts from 0. That's why j should starts with (size - 1)
3 - You are allocating memory from heap, use memset before do something.

Comment: WRONG: sizeof(str).  BETTER: `strlen(str)`.  BEST: `int len = strlen(str); if (len < 1) { handle "bad string" }`  ALSO WRONG: `result = "Forty-two";`.  BETTER: `char * result = strdup("Forty Two");`.  See [man strdup()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)

Comment: Also: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/198264/3135317.  You really don't need malloc/free at all.

Answer (score 1):

On the second line, you should be using `strlen` instead of `sizeof`, because otherwise you will be allocating space for a character pointer and you need more than that.

Comment: They should be using the parameter `size`. That's what it's there for. (But you're right that `sizeof` is not correct.)

Comment: I changed my code to instead use strlen, and was able to properly populate the temp variable. I ran a debugger and saw that through it. However, I catch a segmentation fault when trying to popular the original str variable that I passed through on lines 12-14. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: @IllyaKuzmych did you change the line `result = "Forty-two";` yet?

Comment: Yes, I used memcpy to move the const char* "Forty-two" into the buffer "result"

Answer (score 1):

- sizeof(str) returns size of pointer not length of the literal.
- Array index starts from 0. That's why j should starts with (size - 1)
- You are allocating memory from heap, use memset before do something.

@bereal already says, if you want to understand more, please check this out :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* result = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 10));
    memset(result, 0, 10);

    printf("Addr of result var : %p \n", result);

    result = "Re-assign";

    printf("Addr of result var : %p \n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe my solution gives an idea for you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverseString(char** str, size_t size) {
    char *temp = (char*) malloc(size + 1);
    memset(temp, 0, size + 1);
    int j = size - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i] = str[0][j];
        j--;
    }

    //Change addr of holding str
    *str = temp;

    return;
}


int main() {
    char* result = "Forty-two";

    reverseString(&result, strlen(result));

    printf("%s", result);

    //result holds same addr with temp
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

But there are ways to solve this question more accurately.

Comment: Don't you need `free(temp)` in your function?

Comment: No, When the *str=tmp line executed, str points same addr.

Comment: then when you run `free(result)`, will it release "result" and "temp" memories?