# Store words in an array C

Tags: c, c-strings

I want to write a program that gets input from the user then print the string backwards. I have used the for loop to go through the string. I'm not sure how to store the characters into an array from back to front to then print the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Int main()
{
  char str[100],str1[100];
  int i;

  printf("Input string: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]",str);

i = strlen(str);

for(i;i>=0;i--){
    scanf("%[^\n]",&str1[i]);
}

printf("%s",str1);

return 0;


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: You basically have the loop already, counting down instead of up. All you have to do is to *print* the character of your string, not try to read another string. But remember that `str[strlen(str)]` will be the string terminator character, which you can't really print.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%[^\n]",&str1[i]);` fails as it is blocked by the prior line's `'\n'`.

Check return values of `scanf()`.

I'd expect code to print in the loop, not scan for more input.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` function is for getting the user input. If I understand correctly, you want to get user input and then print it backward, right?

What about printing all the letters consecutively from the right?

Other important remark is the last character in the string is always `\0`. This means a termination of the string and should not be copied to the beginning since it will be interpreted as an empty string. Your loop should avoid copying the last character `\0`, so start `strlen(str)-1`.

This snippet should work:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100],str1[100];
  int i;

  printf("Input string: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  int len = strlen(str)-1;

  for(i=len; i>=0; i--){
    str1[i] = str[len-i];
  }
  // include the last character
  str[len+1] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n",str1);

  return 0;
}
```

We could also consider removing the additional array and do swapping from the left to the right like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100]; // no need for second variable
  int i;

  printf("Input string: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  int len = strlen(str);
  int mid = len / 2; // calculate the middle element

  for(i=0; i<mid; i++){
    char swap = str[len-i-1]; // use "swap" element to temporarily keep value at the specific location
    str[len-i-1] = str[i];
    str[i] = swap;
  }
  str[len] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", str);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: There is also an option to just print the array without swapping: just print values from len-1 to 0 like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];

  printf("Input string: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  int len = strlen(str)-1;

  for(int i=len; i>=0; i--){
    printf("%c", str[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Sorry i am a beginner. But what is this [ str1[i] = str [len-i] ; ]  actually doing . And i would normally use strcpy (str , '\o') to add the null value at the end of the string. I can see you have str [len] = '\0'

Comment: Yes, both approaches are correct. `strcpy` copies an array of `char`s. Because it was a single character, I decided to just modify an array with one item using normal array operations.
The line `str1[i] = str[len-i]` works like that: for i-th element take element of array length decreased by 1. In this example len was just strlen(str), that's why it's -1.
In my solution I wanted to show multiple approaches to the same problem. Last one is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer the below code :**

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];

  printf("Input string: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  int len = strlen(str)-1;

  for(int i=len; i>=0; i--){
    printf("%c", str[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

> **Refer the working sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/9iqN9x7xk)**

[image]